# how to use afterTextChanged to reduce an amount inside a textview

Tags: java, android, double, number-formatting

I am trying to reduce an amount set on a `TextView` using `aftetTextChanged`. To achieve this I am doing the following inside my framgnet

TextWatcher code

```
editTextDiscount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                Double damageCost = 0d;
                String decDE = txtDamageEstimate.getText().toString().trim();
                decDE = decDE.replace("£", "");
                Double decDeResults = Double.valueOf((String) (decDE));

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextDiscount.getText())) {
                    damageCost = editTextDiscount.getCleanDoubleValue();
                }

                txtDiscount.setText(" "+nf.format(-damageCost));
                txtDamageEstimate.setText(nf.format(decDeResults-damageCost));
            }
        });
```

This works however it reduced x2 the amount inputed and when I backspace my input, it wont reset to its original amount e.g if it was 20.00 and I enter 00.01 it will show 19.97 and if i delete that .01 to 0 it will remain 19.97

Comment: check to see how many times `afterTextChanged` is being called ?

Comment: You may need to store the first value before estimating the value.

Comment: hmm seems like its being call twice and called twice again after I backspace in the edittext field

Answer (score 0):

TextWatcher shouldn't be used this way, it is designed as a watcher not an interactor.

I think you try to do something when edit is done. You should use FocusListener instead.

```
txtDiscount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus)
           // here focus is lost, means edit is done, validate text here
    }
```

Comment: I am unable to get any values on txtDamageEstimate from editTextDiscount